# updating values into database using Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have  3 tables

## in models.py

```
class Property(db.Model):
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      agent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
      agent = db.relationship('User')
      description = db.relationship('PropertyDescription',
          collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('language')
)

      property_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('property_type.id'),                               nullable=False)
      sale_details = db.relationship('SaleDetails')
      property_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('property_type.id'),
                             nullable=False)
      property_type = db.relationship('PropertyType')
      sale_details_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sale_details.id'))
      sale_details = db.relationship('SaleDetails')

      def save(self):
         super(Property, self).save()


 class PropertyDescription(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     long_description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
     language = db.Column(db.Enum('de', 'en'), nullable=False)

     property_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('property.id'),
                        nullable=False)

class PropertyType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = db.relationship(
    'PropertyTypeTitle',
       collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('language')
)

class SaleDetails(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

## in views.py

On form.validate_on_submit(),  how can I insert the values to all the tables?
I want to insert data into SaleDetails, PropertyDescription tables and get an id of them. and insert those
values into Property table and also insert id of Property into PropertyDescription table.

I first saved data in property_obj which is Property Object. then

```
 models.Property.save(property_obj)
 sales_obj = models.SaleDetails(price=form.sale_details.data)
 prop_desc_obj = models.PropertyDescription(long_description=form.property_description.data,
                                                    property_id=models.Property.id)
    db.session.add_all(property_obj, sales_obj, prop_desc_obj)
    db.session.commit()
```

But I think i am missing something. with this code I am getting error like
  'Object is not dict-like'

Answer (score 1):

`property()` is a built-in python function. I would advise **not to shadow** builtin functions, as they may cause wonky behavior.

also, `models.Property.save(property_obj)`  is accessing `Property` with a capital P, when your `property` class has a lowercase.

```
property_obj.save()
sales_obj = models.SaleDetails(price=form.sale_details.data)
prop_desc_obj = models.PropertyDescription(long_description=form.property_description.data,
                                                    property_id=property_obj.id)
db.session.add_all(property_obj, sales_obj, prop_desc_obj)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: My mistake. Its Property. I have edited my question.

Comment: should you make an instance of 'Property' first? and save it as an object IE. `my_property = Property()  my_property.save()`

Comment: Yes. I have done that.. property_obj = models.Property(zip=form.zip.data, etc etc) I am reading fields from the form. I have not mentioned all the fields in my question because they are too many. So only the one which I am facing issue, I have mentioned.

Comment: `property_id=models.Property.id)` does not reference `property_obj`  try setting it to `property_id=property_obj.id`

Comment: Ya right. Thats where I am facing problem. I am not getting how to refer back the newly inserted row. I want to insert new entry into 'property' table and it should also insert id's by referring to other tables(ex. sale_details) and i want to insert new row into sale_details and add property'd id as foreign key. Hope my query is clear?

Comment: you should be using created objects, not the class stubs. You're relationships should be built on records (resembled by an object), not by what amounts to the structure of the table. Right now you are trying to link property_id, to an undertermined propery_id, since you are referencing a class structure, not a record of the class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95245/discussion-between-pradeepb-and-busturdust).